# Unable to set background in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, null

I am trying to put a background image into a windows form however, I get this error come up when I press the [image: ...]
 button on BackgroundImage under properties

[image: error]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to skip the required field/property of `docData` control before setting the background image of the Form.

make sure that all required properties of the `docData` control is set properly before setting Background Image of the Form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same thing you're dealing with here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/26c1873c-6a09-4d64-b0de-ef66f13a6fdd/visual-studio-2010-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-docdata?forum=vssetup

so maybe a resource file is missing

Comment: I thought that it may be a resource file, so I made an empty windows form project to compare them, a few was missing but still no luck.

Comment: Here's a known issue with background images in WinForms:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657016/winforms